# Why my view in Debug View Hierarchy in a bit different than the same one on my device?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a draggable view that is a subclass of `UIView` where I create a `subLayer` in `layoutSubviews` method like the following:

```
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width/2, y: draggableRectangleHeight/2)
    bezierPath.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: draggableRectangleHeight/2 - 5, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
    shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor
    layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

The result I'm looking for is fine on my device:

[image]

but in the `Debug View Hierarchy`, it seems the Y axis is reversed:

[image]

Any idea why it's different?

Comment: i don`t see no reversed y axis, what exactly should it look like?

Comment: The layer is actually reversed. The view that includes the green part (the one within the grey border) is normally off the screen. When I pull up the little orange circle, it drags the view. This little circle is at the bottom of the layer in the debug view hierarchy while it is at the top on my device